# How to set color to cell if it is not empty in qtableview?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a table with 26 row, 4 column and in 4th column is the only editable and to set color to the cell if it is not empty and when clicked and edit any cell it should be changed background color , in short when cell on 4th column is non empty cell it should be red color and for other non empty cell no any background color  so looking for basic code structure in QTableView in PyQt5, basically how to structure code if anyone could help to do this thing in QTableview in PyQt5, I have read most of the queries about Background Color but it's very hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a delegate overriden the initStyleOption method:

```py
class ColorDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if option.text.strip(): # condition
            option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QColor("red")
```

```py
delegate = ColorDelegate(tableview)
tableview.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, delegate)
```

Comment: can you suggest from where i can learn about PyQt5 in Advance level??

Comment: If i want to connect two QTableview  and if  I describe in above case if i comment in any column in first QTableview widgets then it should be also changed color in respective cell in another QTableview so can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: @MilanSoliya If you have another question then you must create another post where you provide a [mre] since with what you indicate in the previous comment it does not allow me to understand you

Comment: @MilanSoliya On the other hand if my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: If i want to connect two QTableview  and if  I describe in above case if i comment in any column in first QTableview widgets then it should be also changed color in respective cell in another QTableview so can you help me to solve this problem?                                     In  Details first Qtableview widgets have 26 row and 4 column and 4th one is only editable and second QTableview widgets have 1 row and 26 column , it should be same cell colur in cell index (10,3) in first QTableview and in cell index (0,10) in second QTableview widgets?? how should i connect this two table widgets?

Comment: As I told you if you want help then create another question, the comments are not to answer other questions.

Comment: sure .......@eyllanesc....And Thank you for your generic help in this Question.....